# how to create ejb jar with conditional statement

Tags: java, web-services, ejb, java-ee-7

I have a web service that will be deployed two separate VM (example: VM123 and VM300).
Depending on the VM id (VM123 or VM300), a subset of message driven beans should be deployed.
Is it possible to create ejb-jar.xml with a conditional statement to specify or define the set of mdb's to be deployed VM123 vs VM300 based on a criteria such as environment variable or jndi property?
If so, would you provide an example and/or reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldnt do this programamtically, but use a maven plugin, that includes classes based on environment information specified.

So, somewhere within one of your maven resource plugins, you add profiles which dictate which ejbs beans to include during compilation, and which ones to ignore.

so you could have two profiles:

1. vm01 from which you compile your project with mvn -Pvm01
2. vm02 whence mvn -Pvm02

More details on maven compiler plugin and resource helper plugin:

[Maven Compiler Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/)
[Maven Resources Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/)